# Is there an even faster way to find out when $y=\sin{5x} + \sin{x}$ cuts the x-axis for $0≤x≤\frac{π}{2}$?

Tags: trigonometry

The textbook method suggests using sum to product rules, but I know that someone on MSE will know a superior method! Please share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to find $x$ in that range such that $\sin{5x}=-\sin{x}$ i.e. $x$ that satisfy either of the followings:

$$
\begin{align}
5x+x=k2\pi&\implies x=k\frac{\pi}{3}\\
\\
5x-x=(2k+1)\pi&\implies x=(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{4}
\end{align}
$$

Therefore the only solutions are $x=\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Answer (score 1):

This is pure hindsight and I don't think it's "superior": when $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ or $\frac{\pi}{3}, y=0$. Therefore $y=\sin 5x + \sin x$ cuts through the $x$-axis. But I really don't see the point of doing this.

Comment: @user71207 +1 for the answer.  However, I disagree with the last statement in the answer.  The idea is to solve for $(y = 0)$ with as little math as possible.  When $x = \pi/4, ~4x = \pi \implies 5x = (\pi + x).~~$ When $x = \pi/3, ~5x = (2\pi - x).$  Therefore, the answer given illustrates solutions with (almost) no math.

Comment: yeah this is a neat method. I think it would only be effective for exact values, right?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I did what you did as well after the fact. I guess what I meant is this is a good way to find zeros for someone who doesn't know the sum to product formulas, but not as superior as OP might want (just my personal view). I get your point.